# Unable to do apt update inside the Container

Tags: docker, containers

Please be informed that, I have installed CentOS 8 in my VMWare workstation.

After that I have installed the docker-ce without any issues.

Later i have pulled the httpd image.

```
docker container run --publish 8080:80 --detach httpd
```

Now entered inside the container and trying to do apt update.

```
docker container exec -it 43a bash
root@43a851fddaee:/usr/local/apache2# apt update
```

When I execute the command and getting the below error.

[Error Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5v7Hr.png)

I have tried the same kind in GCP, it works nicely. Please find the screenshot.

[GCP image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hhKZ0.png)

Both VMWare and GCP has same OS. Kindly help me what i need to check.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the screenshot that you posted, it seems like your docker container has no Internet access and this is a common problem with Docker running on Linux machine.

Here are what you need to do on your CentOS 8 VMWare workstation:

1. Execute `sysctl -w net.ipv4.ip_forward=1`
2. Restart docker service `sudo service docker restart`
3. Probably recreate your `httpd` container though I do not think that it is necessary.

The VM on GCP normally already has this flag enabled by default and hence it will work nicely as expected.

Comment: Hi Nguyen, Thanks for the reply. I have tried the above solution but it is not working. still facing the same issue. I have tried to recreate the httpd container but no luck. I have installed the Ubuntu OS in VMWare and created the httpd container image. and update it without any issues. I have checked all the config it is same as CentOS. Please help me how to proceed further. Even in office facing the same issue.

Comment: When installing CentOS and Ubuntu OS, do you need to connect to the Internet? If no, can you check if your VM has Internet access `curl google.com`

Comment: Yes, i have internet connection. Please find the below output. [docker@dockernongui sysctl.d]$ curl www.google.com
<!doctype html><html itemscope="" itemtype="http://schema.org/WebPage" lang="en-IN"><head><meta content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" http-equiv="Content-Type"><meta content="/images/branding/googleg/1x/googleg_standard_color_128dp.png" itemprop="image"><title>Google</title><script nonce="hQN9OyobOLKJIUY+MXKJUQ==">(function(){window.google={kEI:'YjJzXsrmDtaa4-